# Is it possible to nest plugins in django-cms 2?

Tags: django, django-cms

I am trying to have nested plugins in Django-CMS, i.e. a plugin template which itself
contains `placeholder` tags which can be filled with content.

I tried the straightforward way of just putting the tags there and I can add content
via frontend editing, but when I save it, it never shows up.

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not supported?

I am using Django-CMS 2.4.3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to 'render' the child plugins in the plugin template.

I am not sure if {% render_plugin %} is already inplemented in 2.4.... For best experience with nested plugins be sure to upgrade to 3.0

Comment: I am hesitant to upgrade to 3.0 for a production project until it leaves beta.